# Makes all html links clickable when displaying a NSAttributedString in UITextView

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, url, nsattributedstring

I want to display some HTML that contains links (`<a>` tag) in a `UITextView`, and makes those links clickable.

For that I use a `NSAttributedString` initialized with the HTML data and the appropriate options for HTML.

```
NSString* html =   @""
                    "<html>"
                    "<head>"
                    "<base href='http://en.wikipedia.com' target='_self'>"
                    "</head>"
                    "<body>"
                    "<a href='#id'>link</a>"
                    "<a href='http://stackoverflow.com'>link</a>"
                    "</body>"
                    "</html>";

NSAttributedString* attStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[html dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding]
                                                              options:@{
                                                                        NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
                                                                        NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: @(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                                                                       }
                                                   documentAttributes:nil
                                                                error:nil];
```

In the `html` string, you can see two `<a>` links with `href` attributes referring to:

- The stack overflow URL for the first one.
- A URL with only the fragment part for the second one. (https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsurl)

Next, I set the attributed text in the `UITextView`

```
_textView.attributedText = attStr;
```

When executing, all is well displayed in the view, but only the stackoverflow link is clickable. I want to be able to make the other one clickable too. It seems that `NSAttributedString` does not make all html links clickable, but only those with valid URLs.

Any ideas how I could do that using `NSAttributedString`?

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of using UITextView, you may try UIWebView. Because, webview can better handle html codes.

Comment: Don't use `UIWebView`, Apple recommendes to use `WKWebView` instead for iOS 8 and higher.